# Does having infinite scrolling in article listing page affect ad revenue?

Tags: website-design, search

We would like to have infinite scrolling in article listing pages (Category pages) does it affect ad revenue?

Comment: Without knowing how you sell the adverts it's impossible to say really. Are they CPM, CPC or CPA. Do you sell them based on a user spend x mins on a page and the advert being visible the whole time. Also are your adverts placed in amongst the content users are scrolling through or to one side?

Answer (score 1):

In what way do you think it could affect ad revenue? Because you would display different ads on different pages? And with infinite scroll you don't have multiple pages?

I don't think there is a definite answer for this because there are too many factors in play. If one ad is of more quality than the other and generates more clicks, it could affect your ad revenue.
But it all depends on the ad.

But the second question would be if any potential loss in ad revenue weighs up against any potential gain in product revenue with the implementation of a better user experience.
([this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/pagination-infinite-scrolling-load-more-buttons/) by the Baymard Institute talks about an improved UX by stepping away from pagination)

I think A-B testing will give you the answers you want.